# Complexity of a nested geometric sequence

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, analysis

Below code is actually bounded by O(n^2), could anyone please explain why?

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    int j = i;
    while (j < n) {
        do operation with cost O(j)
        j = j * 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? To me it seems O( (n^2)logn ).

Comment: @user1990169 That doesn't contradict it at all.

Comment: @AmiTavory O( (n^2)logn ) does not imply O(n^2) but reverse implication is true.

Comment: @AmiTavory: user1990169 obviously means that it is *not* O(n^2) but *is* O(n^2 log n).

Comment: @j_random_hacker He is misusing *O* for *Theta*. There's a reason for the different terms.

Comment: @user1990169 True; hence, it is not a contradiction. You might want to brush up on your complexity notations.

Comment: @AmiTavory: I agree, but as in *numerous* technical CS papers that "misuse" O in the same way, here context makes the intended meaning unambiguous.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I agree with you on that, but have also seen others that were quite fastidious about the distinction.

Answer (score 4):

It's not that tricky.

---

Your inner loop's complexity forms a [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) with total omplexity *O(n)*.

Without filling the details all the way (this seems like a HW problem), note that the formula for a geometric sequence is

*a_0 (q^k - 1) / q - 1*, (*a_0* = first element, *q* = multiplication factor, *k* = num elements).

and your *q^k* here is *O(n)*.

---

Your outer loop is *O(n)*.

---

Since it's a nested loop, and the inner term does not depend on the outer index, you can multiply.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is geometric progression :)

1. For i = n, the inner loop doesn't execute more than once if i > n/3 (because in next iteration j is >= n).
2. So for 2n/3 iterations of outer loop the inner loop iterates only once and does O(j) operation. So for 2n/3 iterations the complexity is O(n^2).
3. To calculate complexity of remaining iterations set n = n/3, now apply steps 1, 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

Methodically, using Sigma notation, you may do the following:

[image]